# Django Autocomplete with jQuery UI | AJAX | Search | Filter from Database

Tags: html, jquery, django

By using database categories. I am trying to make an input field to be autocomplete in postad form. I
have written this code and while execuiting i am facing the issue. The error which i got i have
pasted below. So i want to make my field to autocomplete

**views.py**

```
def autocomplete(request):
    if 'term' in request.GET:
        qs = vk_categories.objects.filter(cat_name__icontains=request.GET.get('term'))
        titles = list()
        for product in qs:
            titles.append(product.cat_name)
            # titles = [product.title for product in qs]
        return JsonResponse(titles, safe=False)
    return render(request, 'postad.html')
```

**postad.html**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#product").autocomplete({
            //console.log("some");
            source: '{% url 'autocomplete' %}',
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
</script>
```

**html**

```
<form class="valid_form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container5 postadd">
        <h1>Post Ad</h1>
        <p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Title" name="title" maxlength="60">
        </p>
        <p><textarea type="text" placeholder="Write your description.." maxlength="600" name="description"> 
        </textarea></p>
        <input type="text" name="type" id="Categories" placeholder="Search for your categories">
        <p><input type="number" placeholder="Price" name="price" min="0.00" max="100000000000.00" 
step="0.01"/>
        <p class="select_p">
            <input name="state" placeholder="State" type="text">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" name="zip">
        </p>
        <p><input type="file" class="myfile" name="image">
        <input type="file" class="myfile" name="image1"></p
        <p><input type="file" class="myfile" name="image2">
        <input type="file" class="myfile" name="image3"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

see below i attached a error what i getting in console
[image: error screenshot]

Comment: The error show that the line `$("#product").autocomplete({` is not working. Are you sure you have well included the dependency for autocomplete ?

Comment: PostAd:342 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (PostAd:342)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)                                                                         This was the error i am getting

Comment: Use django-select2 https://pypi.org/project/django-select2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

-go to https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

- click on "view source"
- you will find something like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

select and paste before end of your file header.

- Also, copy the 2 lines:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and paste before the end of the body.